# How to automatically running daily PL/SQL script (Oracle) using spring boot and angular?

Tags: java, angular, oracle, spring-boot, eclipse-jee

so my graduation project is about automatically running daily PL/SQL script (Oracle)  using spring boot and angular at a precise hour of the day  with oracle database and im a bit confused cause both langages are new for me can please anyone tell me how to start or if i can find any codings that may help

Comment: Do you want to achieve this with PL/SQL script or Spring? Angular has probably nothing to do with this. Did you check roacle documentation? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse.htm

Answer (score 1):

You could use Oracle scheduler using `DBMS_SCHEDULER` package.

For example,

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
    job_name        => 'your_job',
    program_name    => 'your_program',
    repeat_interval => 'freq=hourly; byminute=0; bysecond=0;',
    job_style       => 'REGULAR',
    enabled         => TRUE);
END;
/
```

See the documentation to learn more about [DBMS_SCHEDULER](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72262).